# Checking a Checkbox through JS in browser

Tags: javascript, checkbox, browser

I'm looking to set multiple values and checkboxes on a webpage using JS.

I'm able to do values using

```
document.querySelector('input[name="date"]').value = '1/1/2000';
document.querySelector('form').submit();
```

...that's simple enough. There are multiple checkboxes that may or may not need to be checked. What is the process to check a box through the console? Here is a sample of one of them when it is checked:

input id="FormView1_cb_EXAMPLE" type="checkbox"

name="FormView1$cb_EXAMPLE" checked="checked"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by targeting the checked attribute of the item after selecting it with either querySelector or getElementByID. Then simply set it to true for checked.

```js
document.querySelector('#steve').checked=true
```

```html
<input id="steve" type="checkbox">
```

If you need to do it to multiple and they all have the same class name, you can use querySelectorAll and a forEach/for loop and set each one to true (checked) using that method. (this would only work if your list of which ones need to be checked conditionally is constant)

Answer (score 0):

I hope your job looks

```js
   var input = document.querySelector('#FormView1_cb_EXAMPLE').checked;
console.log(input)
```

```html
<input id="FormView1_cb_EXAMPLE" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not sure what you mean by "I hope your job looks" though!